# Virtual host installation not working

Tags: localhost, xampp, php.ini

I am trying to instal my existing local server with xampp. 
I setup apache to point  to mywebsite.dev document root to /code/www/public. 
I get an error saying 
The webpage is not accessible. This website has the same address as an external website.

Instructions i m following:

```
Create a folder on your computer for the files 
Edit your host file to add the site name 
Edit httpd-vhosts to add the VirtualHost 
Restart Apache using the XAMPP Control Panel 


127.0.0.1  //Mywebsite.dev

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:\Mywebsite\trunk\www\public
    ServerName //Mywebsite.dev    
    <Directory C:\Mywebsite\trunk\www\public>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>   
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do not use `.dev` as a TLD locally you will run in all sort of problems. It is a valid generic TLD, owned by Google. You should not invent names locally and hope they will work and not create collisions. Instead create a domain name and then just name your resources locally like `something.dev.example.com` or `something.internal.example.com` or `something.private.example.com`, etc. About `.DEV`: https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Answer (score 1):

#### I get an error saying The webpage is not accessible.

There are several mistakes in your configuration.

Your `host` file:

```
127.0.0.1  //Mywebsite.dev
```

- Remove the `//` from the entry in the `hosts` file.

Corrected `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1  Mywebsite.dev
```

Your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:\Mywebsite\trunk\www\public
    ServerName //Mywebsite.dev    
    <Directory C:\Mywebsite\trunk\www\public>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>   
</VirtualHost>
```

- Remove the `//` from the `ServerName`
- Replace `\` with `/`
- Quote the `DocumentRoot` and `Directory`

Corrected `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Mywebsite/trunk/www/public"
    ServerName Mywebsite.dev    
    <Directory "C:/Mywebsite/trunk/www/public">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>   
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: it is saying forbidden access

Comment: @NewPassionnate That's a different problem. Please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem forbidenn access I changed in my httpd-conf:

```
<Directory>
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

by :

```
 <Directory>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   AllowOverride none
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```